# Can we use the value of GetType().ToString() as an identifier to get an object?

Tags: c#, object, identifier

Hi I have an object new Sword() derived from abstract class Item. Can I somehow use a string property Name or this.GetType().ToString() as identifier to refer to a constant object from another class(static). I wan to refer to a bitmap image provided as
 System.Drawing.Bitmap object from another static class. Here is code I have:

Basically:

```
//WORKS
return HeroesPrototype.mapConsts.Bitmaps.sword;
//NOT WORKS 
string Name="sword";
return HeroesPrototype.mapConsts.Bitmaps.<string Name>;    

//More in details:  
abstract class Item:Drawable//class Item will serve as parent for all items(axe,sword, staff etc.) in this case new Sword()
{
    public string  Name { get; set; }//property that I wish to use for identifier
    Bitmap Drawable.GetSprite()//method from Drawable interface that I wish to inherit for all types of item
    {
        return HeroesPrototype.mapConsts.Bitmaps.<string Name>;//Name="sword" is my object identifier
    }
}
namespace HeroesPrototype.mapConsts
{
    public static class Bitmaps
    {
        public static System.Drawing.Bitmap castle = new System.Drawing.Bitmap(Bitmap.FromFile(@"..\..\sprites\mapobj\sword.png"));
    }
}
```

Comment: possibly you need [GetField](http://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/53seyfee(v=vs.110).aspx) and [GetValue](http://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/system.reflection.fieldinfo.getvalue(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: I can only guess about other code not shown here, but your syntax seems me erroneous. May be, this way: `Bitmaps[Name]`?

Comment: I think my syntax is fine since Grundy's answer works great.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

if i understand right you need use [GetField](http://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/53seyfee%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) and [GetValue](http://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/system.reflection.fieldinfo.getvalue%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) something like this

```
Bitmap Drawable.GetSprite()
{
    return (Bitmap)(typeof(HeroesPrototype.mapConsts.Bitmaps)
                   .GetField(Name)
                   .GetValue(null));
}
```